# Trying to get all the collection data from Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting the following Error while trying to get all the data of a Collection from a Firestore

I have a collection names users in my Firestore DB

I am using Firebase Web version 9 (Modular)

```
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "users"));

querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
  console.log(doc.data());
});
```

I am using the code from the Official documentation and still getting that error

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#web-version-9_6

still this is what i get

> TypeError: (0 , lib_firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.collection) is not a function

Answer (score 1):

Have you used the this line in your code -
`import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";` because without importing the collection function won't be accessible and can generate the error.

There are a few possible reasons for this error:

You might have imported the wrong module or a module that does not contain the collection function. Make sure you have imported the Firebase library correctly and that you are using the correct version of the library.

You might have mistyped the name of the function. Make sure you are using the correct spelling and capitalization of the function name.

You might be trying to use the collection function on an object that is not a Firestore instance. The collection function is a method of the Firestore class, so you need to make sure you are calling it on a Firestore instance.

Comment: I have Imported the modules correctly and It is not a spelling problem

Comment: import { auth, db, collection, getDocs } from "lib/firebase";